# Is Facebook shutting down its FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I came across this post :
[Facebook Query Language](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)
and I am really very much worried since the post says that `Facebook`
is going to shut down its `FQL` in coming `August 17, 2016`.
My Most of Facebook based apps uses `FQL`. So is it the time for me to switch to `Graph API` or Is there any alternative that I can use to Quickly move to that `API`.

Thanks for Answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it is time to switch to the Graph API. FQL was marked as deprecated a very long time ago. There is no alternative.